# Pass Parameter To Test Case

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a test case like below:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(UsageCollectiontNecessaryCategory.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    SampleTest1.class,
    SampleTest2.class,
    SampleTest3.class
})
public class AllTest {

}
```

Those three test(SampleTest1, SampleTest2 and SampleTest3) will base on the same data to run. I want to init the parameter in one place and pass it into the three test class. The parameter is an complex object(not a string or int etc) include many data, How can I do that? Or any other good way to do that?

Comment: Rather a java question than a JUnit

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your object I will demonstrate with a string example.

```
package com.yang;

public class ObjectData{

    public String object = "I will be used very often";

}
```

Your Testclasses:

```
package com.yang;

import com.yang.ObjectData;

public class TestOne{

private ObjectData data= new ObjectData();
private String objectInTestClass = new String(data.object);
}
```